# using jobScheduler along with fusedLocation service

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, fusedlocationproviderapi

I use `JobScheduler` to send location of user periodically to the server in background using a `JobService`. I am confused between using time schedules set by `JobScheduler` and the intervals set by `requestLocationUpdates`.

Let assume that I want to send the location every 30 seconds. Should I get only the last Known Location using `getLastLocation()` every time the secheduler runs using  `setMinimumLatency(30000)`? or I should run the scheduler just **once** and then let the FusedLocationApi to send location every 30 seconds using `mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);`?

If both of methods are OK, Which one is preferred to send location in a background service?

Currently I have intervals both on JobScheduler and FusedLocationApi but I can not decide what to do next:

This is my scheduler in MainActivity:

```
    ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(this, LocationMonitoringService.class);
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
    builder.setMinimumLatency(30 * 1000); // wait at least
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(30 * 1000); // maximum delay
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler = this.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

and this is my LocationMonitoringService:

```
public class LocationMonitoringService extends JobService implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();
    boolean isWorking = false;
    boolean jobCancelled = false;
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        mLocationClient.connect();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before being completed.");
        jobCancelled = true;
        boolean needsReschedule = isWorking;
        jobFinished(jobParameters, needsReschedule);
        return needsReschedule;
    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google API");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "== location != null");
            //Send result to Server
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API");

    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck on the issue? You were fixed it?

Comment: I have finally called the scheduler just once and let the Location service to repeat the job. However I am not sure how it works and when it stops working... @AneesDeen

Comment: @AliSheikhpour did you solution kept working on Android O+?